# "Clone" frequencies (roughly) from a Web Audio stream onto another white noise stream

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I want to take an input audio stream from the microphone, take the gain of the frequencies of that stream and copy that information to another white noise audio stream.

The goal is that the same frequencies that are loud in the input stream are also loud in the output (white noise) stream.

Is this possible?

I can imagine to take an analyser node to get the frequency information from the input, but how to copy it onto the output? Would I need to use a separate filter node for each frequency?

Or is it maybe more sense-full to use the analyser information directly for the white noise generation?

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like a vocoder.  I built one in Web Audio: webaudiodemos.appspot.com/Vocoder/.

Comment: "Vocoder" is a good starting point! Is there a name for the algorithm I would need especially? Or a function in your code? Is it this [Linear prediction-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocoder#Linear_prediction-based) thing?